# How can I delete the first zero(s) in a string? (Without using atoi)

Tags: c

I was making a script that is calculating the additions between two natural numbers which decimal lengths should be smaller or same with 10000, and printing a result of the sum.

Of course, there ain't any variable type that can hold a integer which length is 10000 in C.

So, I made the program by utilizing the simple additions' calculating logic that all we learn in a school when we were young. And also, I just should use strings to get those gigantic numbers.

But some results were starting with zero. I knew why did the zero appeared there, but I did prefer to have a result that is like "1234", not "01234". By the way, all other stuffs were perfect.

I needed a function that gets input as string, and erases a single zero starts with a string if it exists.

And could you make it instead of me, please? You should probably consider that the strings we will deal with can have such a length that is smaller or same with 10000.

Comment: I don't understand what you want

Comment: Using `strspn()` makes for a one-liner function. No loop needed.

Comment: Or `strpbrk` with `"0123456789"` as the *accept* string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
char * f( char * str )
{
    while ( *str == '0' && str[1] )
        str++; // skips all zero-s when it is not last character in string

    return str;
}
```

Comment: @davidcrankin actually the code *is* correct because && short-circuits! The [1] is so that it works correctly for "0"

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `str[1]` isn't doing what you think. It is to check whether `*str` is the last digit. In your version the `*str &&`  is redundant.

Comment: `*str == '0' && str[1]` is equal to `str[0] == '0' && str[1]` and it means: "While first character is ASCII zero (0x30) and next character is not end of string (0)". `str[1]` is protection for case when right-most character is `'0'` - in this case it has to stay. For example if you send "000" the result will be "0" instead of empty string.